# Standard USB OTG to USB C IC

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have a board that supports USB-OTG, with an integrated PHY in my MCU. It's fairly trivial to support a keyed connector (like Micro-B), but I figure USB-C would need a seperate chip to handle the non-keyed connector.

If I have the following pins from the MCU, ***I am looking for a chip that will, on the other side, handle the USB-C side of it.*** I'm missing some google terms to get exactly what I want.

- USB D+/D-
- 5V_USB_OTG
- USB_OTG_ID
- Optional USB_OTG_PWR (which I am not sure exactly what it does, it's only mentioned twice in the reference manual).

The specific CPU I am using is the iMXRT1024, and the USB speeds are only 2.0.

Ideally we would retain the USB-OTG capability. We would like to be able to connect a laptop to the board, or connect a flash drive to the board as well. The USB is used to update firmware and configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You have an OTG device. It is either host or device. The USB pins being host or device is defined by the ID pin. In host mode it must output power out. In device mode it must sense when 5V is present to be allowed to communicate as device.

You just need to adapt that to a Type-C connector, and special chips called Type-C controllers exist. But they likely do not allow to convert a legacy USB 2.0 OTG interface to Type-C directly.

The MCU could sense itself if there is nothing or a host or a device connected, and set the ID pin accordinly, unless it can be skipped and overridden in software. All it needs to do is to monitor the CC pins for host pull-ups or device pull-downs.

But it might be impossible to implement the interface in a compliant way without official controller Ic. You may need to be able to detect and provide the auxiliary VConn supply to an active USB cable.